# How can I start Windows Updates on 10 Windows 2016 servers remotely using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-update

I have 10 domain joined Windows 2016 servers. I need to run Windows updates on them, I don't want to logon on to each of them, and then manually start Windows Updates.

I found that you can do it with;

```
Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate
```

But I don't know how exactly.

**** Update; thanks to duenni, this was my final solution. Install PSWindowsUpdate modules and then;

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts –Value * -Force

$Script = {import-module PSWindowsUpdate; Get-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -Install -Verbose -AutoReboot | Out-File C:\PSWindowsUpdate.log}

Invoke-WUjob -ComputerName s10,s11,s12,s13,s14,s15,s16,s17,s18,s19,s20 -Script $Script -Confirm:$false -RunNow
```

Comment: Invoke-WUInstall actually creates a task and runs it under SYSTEM. So not to over-complicate things when not needed I just use wuauclt /detectnow /updatenow run remotely.

Comment: As a workaround you can install PSWindowsUpdate in a version with `Invoke-WUInstall` by using `Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate -MaximumVersion 1.5.2.6`

Comment: `wuauclt` is deprecated on Windows 10 and Server 2016.

Comment: Yes, in 10 and later theres a new tool called UsoClient.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Release Notes](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWindowsUpdate/2.1.1.2) (click on "Package Details") the command `Invoke-WUInstall` has been replaced by `Invoke-WUJob` in Version 2.0.0.

Try

```
$Script = {import-module PSWindowsUpdate; Get-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -Install | Out-File C:\PSWindowsUpdate.log}

Invoke-WUjob -ComputerName $computer -Script $Script -Confirm:$false -RunNow
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, I get this error when I run it; Invoke-WUjob : [c12] Connecting to remote server c12 failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the re
quest.  Default credentials with Negotiate over HTTP can be used only if the target machine is part of the TrustedHosts list or the A
llow implicit credentials for Negotiate option is specified. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

Comment: Take a look at `Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts`.

Comment: To just trust every client `Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts –Value * -Force`. You can also use a GPO for this.

Comment: Thanks duenni, I've only added the reboot option, and than it's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

As a direct equivalent to Invoke-WUInstall you could actually invoke Get-WUInstall using Invoke-Command.

- Make sure you have the latest [PSWindowsUpdate](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc/).
- Change PowerShell’s Execution Policy to RemoteSigned. The RSEP allows PowerShell scripts as long as they are signed by a trusted publisher. Type `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` and press Enter. Confirm when prompted.
- For PS 2.0 Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate (not needed after 3.0)

`GetWUInstall` supports many nice things, but by far the most useful are:

- `Get-WUInstall –MicrosoftUpdate –ListOnly` --> will list available updates from the Microsoft Update servers
- `Get-WUInstall –MicrosoftUpdate` --> will ask for each update if to install or not (very useful in recent times)
- `Get-WUInstall –MicrosoftUpdate –AcceptAll` --> automatically accept all
- adding –`AutoReboot` --> will also reboot after updating

Many more things are supported like hiding, un-hiding or installing specific KBs. You can use `Help Get-WUInstall –full` to see all supported features.

Comment: When I use Get-WUInstall I get a 'Access is denied.' error, see update... I've tested it locally, and that works.

Comment: You can't run this remotely, thats why `Invoke-WUInstall`/`Invoke-WUJob` are using the workaround and create a scheduled task on the remote machine.